# how to apply when condition in different way of paremeter in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to create an Ansible playbook.  When I enter `1` then my add user playbook run and when I enter `2` then my remove playbook will run.

How can I solve my problem? I am stuck in the `when` condition.  After `when` module what should I write to bypass the user input

```
hosts: "35.171.87.230"
tasks: 
- 
 include: extreme.yml 
 name: "including add user"
 static: false
 when: "ansible_user_input == \"1\""
 vars_prompt: 
- name: "entering the no" 
  prompt: "enter the no"

become: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it at runtime as a variable trigger with --extra-vars rather than complicating the logic of your playbook.

```
ansible-playbook ...  --extra-vars myAction=add
```